# Display multiple images in PIL

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

## -------------------------------Solved(Partially)----------------------------------------

My problem is that when I try to display multiple images on the canvas using PIL, I end up with only the last image.
All the images have slightly different characteristics(angle offset). Also the having a plethora of entries, I have to use a loop for sure. Also I'll need to use PIL(tkinter objects not possible) for the angle offset feature.

Here is the code;

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Filename: weather_sim.py
import os
import tkinter as tk
import h5py as hp
import numpy as np
import ntpath as ntp
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename



def path_leaf(path):
    head, tail = ntp.split(path)
    return tail or ntp.basename(head)



class CoordFind:


    def __init__(self):

        self.LatPx = 0
        self.LonPx = 0


    def find_px(self, Lat, Lon):

        self.LatPx = (Lat - LatN)/LatLc
        self.LonPx = (Lon - LonW)/LonLc




class PlottingGUI(tk.Frame):


    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.coord = CoordFind()

        self.root = parent
        self.root.wm_title("-|-|-|-|||Wind Vector Plotter|||-|-|-|-")
        self.root.resizable(False, False)

        self.path = "None Selected"
        self.HaM = 0
        self.Lat = 0
        self.Lon = 0
        self.WiD = 0
        self.WiS = 0

        self.fr = tk.Frame(self.root, width = (width+20), height = (height+20), bd = 2)
        self.fr.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.frBro = tk.Frame(self.root, width = (width+20), height = 50, bd = 2)
        self.frBro.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.frHi = tk.Frame(self.root, width = (width+20), height = 50, bd = 2)
        self.frHi.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

        self.cv = tk.Canvas(self.fr, width = width, height = height, background = "white", bd = 0, relief = tk.SUNKEN)
        self.cv.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.cv.create_image(1, 1, anchor = "nw", image = photo)

        self.broButton = tk.Button(self.frBro, text = "Browse Dsets", command = self.analyseDset, height = 3, width = 16, bg = "yellow")
        self.broButton.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 20)
        self.selFile = tk.Label(self.frBro, text = self.path)
        self.selFile.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        self.caution = tk.Label(self.frHi, text = "Optional use. Warning!!, May lead to lags in program", fg = "red")
        self.caution.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        self.shoRedBut = tk.Button(self.frHi, text = "Show H1", command = self.show_barbs1().__next__, height = 3, width = 16, bg = "#FF0000", fg = "white", activebackground="#E533B5")
        self.shoRedBut.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 7, pady = 2)
        self.shoGrnBut = tk.Button(self.frHi, text = "Show H2", command = self.show_barbs2().__next__, height = 3, width = 16, bg = "#00B400", fg = "white", activebackground="#B5E533")
        self.shoGrnBut.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 7, pady = 2)
        self.shoBluBut = tk.Button(self.frHi, text = "Show H3", command = self.show_barbs3().__next__, height = 3, width = 16, bg = "#0000FF", fg = "white", activebackground="#33B5E5")
        self.shoBluBut.grid(row = 1, column = 2, padx = 7, pady = 2)

        self.desc1 = tk.Label(self.frHi, text = "100-250 hPa", fg = "white", bg = "black")
        self.desc1.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        self.desc2 = tk.Label(self.frHi, text = "250-350 hPa", fg = "white", bg = "black")
        self.desc2.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        self.desc3 = tk.Label(self.frHi, text = "350-700 hPa", fg = "white", bg = "black")
        self.desc3.grid(row = 2, column = 2)


    def analyseDset(self): 
        self.path = askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Dataset files", "*.h5")
                                                    ,("All files", "*.*") ))
        self.jfname = path_leaf(self.path)
        self.selFile = tk.Label(self.frBro, text = self.jfname)
        self.selFile.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        self.extDset()


    def extDset(self):
        hf = hp.File(self.path, 'r')

        HaM = hf.get('HEIGHT_ASSIGNMENT_METHOD')
        Lat = hf.get('Latitude')
        Lon = hf.get('Longitude')
        WiD = hf.get('WIND_DIRECTION')
        WiS = hf.get('WIND_SPEED')

        self.HaM = np.array(HaM)
        self.Lat = np.array(Lat)/100
        self.Lon = np.array(Lon)/100
        self.WiD = np.array(WiD)
        self.WiS = np.array(WiS)

        self.BrbImR = np.empty((self.HaM.shape[0],1))
        self.BrbImB = np.empty((self.HaM.shape[0],1))



    def show_barbs1(self):

        self.coord = CoordFind()
        script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        im = Image.open(os.path.join(script_dir, 'Red_Barbs\icons8-wind-speed-43-47-50.png'))
        w, h = im.size
        im = im.resize((int(w/2), int(h/2)), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        vec_im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im.rotate(45))

        for i in range(0, self.HaM.shape[0]):
            if self.HaM[i] == 0:
                self.coord.find_px(self.Lat[i], self.Lon[i])
                x = self.coord.LonPx
                y = self.coord.LatPx
                self.BrbImR[i] = self.cv.create_image(x, y, image = vec_im)

        while True:
            for i in range(0, self.HaM.shape[0]):
                self.cv.itemconfigure(self.BrbImR[i], state = tk.NORMAL)
            self.shoRedBut.configure(text = "Showing H1")
            yield


    def show_barbs2(self):

        self.coord = CoordFind()
        BrbImG = np.empty((self.HaM.shape[0],1))
        script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        im = Image.open(os.path.join(script_dir, 'Green_Barbs\icons8-wind-speed-43-47-50.png'))
        w, h = im.size
        im = im.resize((int(w/2), int(h/2)), Image.ANTIALIAS)

        for i in range(0, self.HaM.shape[0]):
            if self.HaM[i] == 1:
                vec_im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im.rotate(self.WiD[i]))
                self.coord.find_px(self.Lat[i], self.Lon[i])
                x = self.coord.LonPx
                y = self.coord.LatPx
                BrbImG[i] = self.cv.create_image(x, y, image = vec_im)

        while True:
            for i in range(0, self.HaM.shape[0]):
                self.cv.itemconfigure(BrbImG[i], state = tk.NORMAL)
            self.shoGrnBut.configure(text = "Showing H2")
            yield


    def show_barbs3(self):

        self.coord = CoordFind()
        script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        im = Image.open(os.path.join(script_dir, 'Blue_Barbs\icons8-wind-speed-43-47-50.png'))
        w, h = im.size
        im = im.resize((int(w/2), int(h/2)), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        vec_im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im.rotate(180))

        for i in range(0, self.HaM.shape[0]):
            if self.HaM[i] == 2:    
                self.coord.find_px(self.Lat[i], self.Lon[i])
                x = self.coord.LonPx
                y = self.coord.LatPx
                self.BrbImB[i] = self.cv.create_image(x, y, image = vec_im)

        while True:
            for i in range(0, self.HaM.shape[0]):
                self.cv.itemconfigure(self.BrbImB[i], state = tk.NORMAL)
            self.shoBluBut.configure(text = "Showing H3")
            yield




if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = tk.Tk()

    backmap = "Map.png"
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = backmap)
    width = photo.width()
    height = photo.height()

    LatN = 69.5
    LatS = -69.3
    LonE = 148.9
    LonW = 1.0

    LatLc = (LatS - LatN)/height
    LonLc = (LonE - LonW)/width

    app = PlottingGUI(root)

    root.mainloop()
```

The output currently is this;(For the green arrows as that is what I have tested on)
[image]
This is what I want;(But with different angles)
[image]
I am using Python 3.6 on Windows 10.
Thanks in advance!!

## P.S.: Also there is another problem if someone can help me with that. I would like to be able to choose a particular image based on a range factor(Wind Speed) by doing like a switch-case(or if-elif-else) procedure if possible. But when I try to do that it says "No such File or Directory". I may put it in another Question though.

## -------------------------------Solved(Till this point)---------------------------------

> EDIT: Solved the problem of displaying multiple arrows according to
>   choice and at different angles.

Here's the code;

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Filename: weather_sim.py
import os
import tkinter as tk
import h5py as hp
import numpy as np
import ntpath as ntp
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename



def path_leaf(path):
    head, tail = ntp.split(path)
    return tail or ntp.basename(head)



class CoordFind:


    def __init__(self):

        self.LatPx = 0
        self.LonPx = 0


    def find_px(self, Lat, Lon):

        self.LatPx = (Lat - LatN)/LatLc
        self.LonPx = (Lon - LonW)/LonLc




class PlottingGUI(tk.Frame):


    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.coord = CoordFind()

        self.root = parent
        self.root.wm_title("-|-|-|-|||Wind Vector Plotter|||-|-|-|-")
        self.root.resizable(False, False)

        self.path = "None Selected"
        self.HaM = 0
        self.Lat = 0
        self.Lon = 0
        self.WiD = 0
        self.WiS = 0
        self.ima = []

        self.fr = tk.Frame(self.root, width = (width+20), height = (height+20), bd = 2)
        self.fr.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.frBro = tk.Frame(self.root, width = (width+20), height = 50, bd = 2)
        self.frBro.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.frHi = tk.Frame(self.root, width = (width+20), height = 50, bd = 2)
        self.frHi.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

        self.cv = tk.Canvas(self.fr, width = width, height = height, background = "white", bd = 0, relief = tk.SUNKEN)
        self.cv.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.cv.create_image(1, 1, anchor = "nw", image = photo)

        self.broButton = tk.Button(self.frBro, text = "Browse Dsets", command = self.analyseDset, height = 3, width = 16, bg = "yellow")
        self.broButton.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 20)
        self.selFile = tk.Label(self.frBro, text = self.path)
        self.selFile.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        self.caution = tk.Label(self.frHi, text = "Optional use. Warning!!, May lead to lags in program", fg = "red")
        self.caution.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        self.shoRedBut = tk.Button(self.frHi, text = "Show H1", command = self.show_barbs1().__next__, height = 3, width = 16, bg = "#FF0000", fg = "white", activebackground="#E533B5")
        self.shoRedBut.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 7, pady = 2)
        self.shoGrnBut = tk.Button(self.frHi, text = "Show H2", command = self.show_barbs2().__next__, height = 3, width = 16, bg = "#00B400", fg = "white", activebackground="#B5E533")
        self.shoGrnBut.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 7, pady = 2)
        self.shoBluBut = tk.Button(self.frHi, text = "Show H3", command = self.show_barbs3().__next__, height = 3, width = 16, bg = "#0000FF", fg = "white", activebackground="#33B5E5")
        self.shoBluBut.grid(row = 1, column = 2, padx = 7, pady = 2)

        self.desc1 = tk.Label(self.frHi, text = "100-250 hPa", fg = "white", bg = "black")
        self.desc1.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        self.desc2 = tk.Label(self.frHi, text = "250-350 hPa", fg = "white", bg = "black")
        self.desc2.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        self.desc3 = tk.Label(self.frHi, text = "350-700 hPa", fg = "white", bg = "black")
        self.desc3.grid(row = 2, column = 2)


    def analyseDset(self): 
        self.path = askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Dataset files", "*.h5")
                                                    ,("All files", "*.*") ))
        self.jfname = path_leaf(self.path)
        self.selFile = tk.Label(self.frBro, text = self.jfname)
        self.selFile.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        self.extDset()


    def extDset(self):
        hf = hp.File(self.path, 'r')

        HaM = hf.get('HEIGHT_ASSIGNMENT_METHOD')
        Lat = hf.get('Latitude')
        Lon = hf.get('Longitude')
        WiD = hf.get('WIND_DIRECTION')
        WiS = hf.get('WIND_SPEED')

        self.HaM = np.array(HaM)
        self.Lat = np.array(Lat)/100
        self.Lon = np.array(Lon)/100
        self.WiD = np.array(WiD)
        self.WiS = np.array(WiS)

        self.BrbImR = np.empty((self.HaM.shape[0],1))
        self.BrbImG = np.empty((self.HaM.shape[0],1))
        self.BrbImB = np.empty((self.HaM.shape[0],1))



    def barb_def(self, WiS):

        if WiS < 1:
            self.ima = "1.png"
        elif WiS < 3:
            self.ima = "2.png"
        elif WiS < 8:
            self.ima = "3.png"
        elif WiS < 13:
            self.ima = "4.png"
        elif WiS < 18:
            self.ima = "5.png"
        elif WiS < 23:
            self.ima = "6.png"
        elif WiS < 28:
            self.ima = "7.png"
        elif WiS < 33:
            self.ima = "8.png"
        elif WiS < 38:
            self.ima = "9.png"
        elif WiS < 43:
            self.ima = "10.png"
        elif WiS < 48:
            self.ima = "11.png"
        elif WiS < 53:
            self.ima = "12.png" 
        elif WiS < 58:
            self.ima = "13.png"
        elif WiS < 63:
            self.ima = "14.png"
        elif WiS < 68:
            self.ima = "15.png"
        elif WiS < 73:
            self.ima = "16.png"
        elif WiS < 78:
            self.ima = "17.png"
        elif WiS < 83:
            self.ima = "18.png"
        elif WiS < 88:
            self.ima = "19.png"
        elif WiS < 93:
            self.ima = "20.png"
        elif WiS < 98:
            self.ima = "21.png"
        elif WiS < 103:
            self.ima = "22.png"
        else:
            self.ima = "23.png"


    def show_barbs1(self):

        self.coord = CoordFind()
        vec_im = []
        im = []
        p = []
        script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))        
        for i in range(0, self.HaM.shape[0]):
            self.barb_def(self.WiS[i])
            p.append("{}{}".format('Red_Barbs\\', self.ima))
            im.append(Image.open(os.path.join(script_dir, p[i])))
            w, h = im[i].size
            im[i] = im[i].resize((int(w/2), int(h/2)), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            vec_im.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(im[i].rotate(self.WiD[i])))

        for i in range(0, self.HaM.shape[0]):
            if self.HaM[i] == 0:
                self.coord.find_px(self.Lat[i], self.Lon[i])
                x = self.coord.LonPx
                y = self.coord.LatPx
                self.BrbImR[i] = self.cv.create_image(x, y, image = vec_im[i])

        while True:
            for i in range(0, self.HaM.shape[0]):
                self.cv.itemconfigure(self.BrbImR[i], state = tk.NORMAL)
            self.shoRedBut.configure(text = "Showing H1")
            yield


    def show_barbs2(self):

        self.coord = CoordFind()
        vec_im = []
        im = []
        p = []
        script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

        for i in range(0, self.HaM.shape[0]):
            self.barb_def(self.WiS[i])
            p.append("{}{}".format('Green_Barbs\\', self.ima))
            im.append(Image.open(os.path.join(script_dir, p[i])))
            w, h = im[i].size
            im[i] = im[i].resize((int(w/2), int(h/2)), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            vec_im.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(im[i].rotate(self.WiD[i])))

        for i in range(0, self.HaM.shape[0]):
            if self.HaM[i] == 1:
                self.coord.find_px(self.Lat[i], self.Lon[i])
                x = self.coord.LonPx
                y = self.coord.LatPx
                self.BrbImG[i] = self.cv.create_image(x, y, image = vec_im[i])

        while True:
            for i in range(0, self.HaM.shape[0]):
                self.cv.itemconfigure(self.BrbImG[i], state = tk.NORMAL)
            self.shoGrnBut.configure(text = "Showing H2")
            yield


    def show_barbs3(self):

        self.coord = CoordFind()
        vec_im = []
        im = []
        p = []
        script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

        for i in range(0, self.HaM.shape[0]):
            self.barb_def(self.WiS[i])
            p.append("{}{}".format('Blue_Barbs\\', self.ima))
            im.append(Image.open(os.path.join(script_dir, p[i])))
            w, h = im[i].size
            im[i] = im[i].resize((int(w/2), int(h/2)), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            vec_im.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(im[i].rotate(self.WiD[i])))


        for i in range(0, self.HaM.shape[0]):
            if self.HaM[i] == 2:    
                self.coord.find_px(self.Lat[i], self.Lon[i])
                x = self.coord.LonPx
                y = self.coord.LatPx
                self.BrbImB[i] = self.cv.create_image(x, y, image = vec_im[i])

        while True:
            for i in range(0, self.HaM.shape[0]):
                self.cv.itemconfigure(self.BrbImB[i], state = tk.NORMAL)
            self.shoBluBut.configure(text = "Showing H3")
            yield




if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = tk.Tk()

    backmap = "Map.png"
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = backmap)
    width = photo.width()
    height = photo.height()

    LatN = 69.5
    LatS = -69.3
    LonE = 148.9
    LonW = 1.0

    LatLc = (LatS - LatN)/height
    LonLc = (LonE - LonW)/width

    app = PlottingGUI(root)

    root.mainloop()
```

## But this ended up having a new problem. One set of coloured arrows is showing at a time but when I click the button to display another set it goes "Python stopped working because of some error" and then the shell restarts. Don't know what's the prob though.

Comment: Please make a github repo (or similar) that contains all the images and some example data so that I can test it.

Comment: @Novel: I don't think that's a good idea. Better to simulate this with text instead of images, or embed a couple of very small images. The github repo would likely go away or be updated some day, rendering this question useless. What we need is a _small_ [mcve] because currently there appears to be a lot of code unrelated to the question being asked.

Comment: Yes you are correct @BryanOakley. It is actually more directed towards wind data extraction and simulation. This will be only a sub-module to supply the fuctions to the main program.

Comment: @Novel if possible please try with your own set of images. An example code would be better than actually editing my whole code. If you still do need the pictorial and dataset resources please leave a comment. I would happily make a dedicated repo for it.

Comment: @BryanOakley if needed I wouldn't mind keeping the repo intact as it is for future use for the sake of the question. I would be happy if it ends up helping others too. :D

Comment: You can keep the repo intact for your own needs, but that doesn't make the question any better. We should be able to get everything we need directly from the question. The reason we can't is possibly why you haven't seen any answers yet.

Comment: Just updated the code. Basic problems have been solved. But new problem aroused

Comment: Thanks for the tip though @BryanOakley. Will remember that for future questions.